# TypeScript type declaration (d.ts) for destructing function payload

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

Using WebStorm. TypeScript v4.6.2

I have a function inside regular JavaScript file `index.js`. Next to it I have types declaration file `index.d.ts`. The sole purpose of this type declaration file is to get autocomplete suggestions.

Inside JS file I have a function:

```js
module.exports.myFunction = async ({foo}) => {
  foo. // <-- expecting to get suggestion "bar"
}
```

How TypeScript types declaration file need to look to provide autocomplete for `bar` which is inside of this `foo`?

Trying to do like so:

```js
interface payload {
  foo: {
    bar: string;
  };
}

declare function myFunction(object: payload): any;

export default myFunction;
```

Getting such "suggestions":

[image]

If I require this `myFunction` from any other location, then I do get the suggestions as expected, but I want to get that suggestion inside of `myFunction` itself:

[image]

Files structure:

[image]

Comment: AFAIK .d.ts files are to provide autocomplete for people using your index.js so won't be available while still writing it

Comment: @apokryfos Check answer below, it did the trick and it works perfectly fine now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71510456/1737158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not work in a magic way, in your case the best way to make it work is to export the interface and import it in a JSDoc comment to be usable in the function typing. So your files should look like this:

```
// index.d.ts file

export interface Payload { // Interface name should be capitalized
  foo: {
    bar: string;
  };
}
```

```js
// index.js file

/**
 * @typedef {import('.').Payload} Payload
 */

/**
 * @param {Payload} param
 */
const myFunction = async ({ foo }) => {
  foo. // <-- You will get here the suggestion for "bar"
};

module.exports = { myFunction };
```

Comment: it does work, thanks 